# Create matplotlib subplots for columns names with similar pattern

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with timeseries data for 10 different gas wells with similar data variables. The data set looks like this:

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I9qP.png)

I have defined a dict of well names (`well_names`) and variables (`variable_names`) and would like to create a scatter subplot (2 x 5) for all wells, however it is not possible to show the specific plot in each specific subplot, but all the data in the last subplot... below the code I was working with:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(20,20))

axes_list = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist] 

a == 'Qg'

b == 'WHP'

for i in range(1,11):
    for pozo in well_names:
        plt.scatter(dftr[pozo+a],dftr[pozo+b])
        plt.ylim(1400,1700)
        plt.xlim(60,110)
        plt.title(pozo)
i= i+1
plt.show()
                      
for ax in axes_list:
    ax.remove()
```

[image]

Comment: You have to address the axes objects. `plt.scatter()` uses the current axis object, i.e., the last one created. Please read the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).